# XSLT whitespace control with text output

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Using xsltproc, how can I output CDATA sections without surrounding space, if the formatter I need to use formats around CDATA like this by inserting space? No requirement to use xsl:text. I also tried xsl:value-of but could not figure out how to use CDATA in xsl:value-of.  (I can delete the space around CDATA, but the formatter simply adds it back).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent='no' />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>
            <![CDATA[/*
*    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*/
]]>
        </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>
            <![CDATA[/*
*    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*/
]]>
        </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
jonsmirl@ares:~/aosp/blogs/jonsmirl.github.io/xml$ xsltproc test.xsl test.xsl

            /*
*    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*/

        
            /*
*    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*/

        jonsmirl@ares:~/aosp/blogs/jonsmirl.github.io/xml$
```

Desired output

```
jonsmirl@ares:~/aosp/blogs/jonsmirl.github.io/xml$ xsltproc test.xsl test.xsl
/*
*    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*/
/*
*    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*/
jonsmirl@ares:~/aosp/blogs/jonsmirl.github.io/xml$
```

This solution works, my mistake was in thinking the text needed to be inside CDATA to get the formatter to leave it alone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent='no' />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>/*
*    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*/
</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>/*
*    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*/
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why any CDATA section? If you want to control whitespace and indentation `xsl:text` is the tool.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works, my mistake was in thinking the text needed to be inside CDATA to get the formatter to leave it alone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent='no' />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>/*
*    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*/
</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>/*
*    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*/
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```